# How to list photos by date in folders?

Tags: directory, photo-management, visualization

I have many photos in a folders but I am not able to see the details of the shooting, so I am not able to order them by time.

I can only view the last modify time

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with default setting

Comment: Doesn't Ubuntu have the `Created on` field?

Comment: Did you try ``Shotwell` or `digiKam` photo managers?

Comment: Please specify your Ubuntu version and file manager (if not default) used.

Comment: You can use shotwell for that.

Answer (score 0):

check the size of the photos.

Nautilus have fixed size to view, if not mistaken is something less than 10MB for viewing.

Comment: The size? Why the size?

Comment: THe size in folder, this size.